# Controller method to add a product, stored across three database tables

Tags: php, database, controller, atomic, cakephp

I have some questions on how I can improve this "add" action method in a controller.

Using a single form, the user can upload a product to be displayed on the site.  A **Product** is composed of three entities: `Product`, `ProductFeatures` and `ProductMedias` (stored in three database tables).

To prepare data for insertion and upload, I have created two helper classes with static methods to simplify the controllers. (This approach should help with rollback if necessary).

In one action (the `add` method of `Products` controller), I do multiple tasks:

1. The `setProductByForm` method in `ProductsTable` creates an empty `Product` entity, populates it with form data, and saves it in the database.

   ```
   public function setProductByForm($form)
   {
        $product = $this->newEntity();
        $product = $this->patchEntity($product, $form);
        return $this->save($product);
   }
   ```
2. The `uploadFiles` method in `UploadFilesComponent` stores the common images.
3. A method in the `ModelUtils` class calls other methods that prepare and tranform the data in entities.

   ```
   public static function prepareProductsFeatures($formValues, $productId)
   {
       $productFeaturesArray = self::createProductsFeaturesArray($formValues);
       $productFeaturesEntities = self::createProductsFeaturesEntitiesArray(
           $productFeaturesArray, $productId
       );
       return $productFeaturesEntities;
   }
   ```
4. I create the URL where thumbnail will stored (using a method in the `UploadUtils` class).

   ```
   public static function getOutputThumbUrl($mainImage, $productId)
   {
       return str_replace(PRODUCTS_IMAGES_FOLDER . $productId,
           PRODUCTS_THUMB_FOLDER, $mainImage);
   }
   ```
5. The thumbnail is stored.
6. Methods in `ModelUtils` transform data into entities and save them in `MediasTable`.

What is the best way to separate concepts and operations?

Note: I've tried to use `afterSave` but it's impossible to access `request->data` from it.

### Controller action

```
public function add()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $productSaved = $this->Products->setProductByForm($this->request->data);

        if($productSaved)
        {
            $this->loadModel('ProductFeatures');
            $productFeaturesSaved = $this->ProductFeatures->setProductFeaturesEntities(
                ModelUtils::prepareProductsFeatures($this->request->data, $productSaved['id'])
            );

            $imagesUploaded = $this->UploadFile->uploadFiles(
                PRODUCTS_IMAGES_FOLDER . $productSaved['id'], $this->request->data['file']
            );

            $outputThumbUrl = UploadUtils::getOutputThumbUrl($imagesUploaded[0]['url'], $productSaved['id']);

            $thumbUploaded = $this->UploadFile->resizeImage([
                'input' => $imagesUploaded[0]['url'], 'output' => $outputThumbUrl,
                'width' => 250, 'height' => 250, 'mode' => 'stretch'
            ]);

            $this->loadModel('Medias');
            $thumbSaved = $this->Medias->setMediaEntity(
                ModelUtils::prepareMediaThumb($productSaved['id'], $outputThumbUrl)
            );
            $mediasSaved = $this->Medias->setMediasEntities(
                ModelUtils::prepareMedias($imagesUploaded, $productSaved['id'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

### Full source code

- [ProductsController class](http://pastebin.com/TQ1trw3Y)
- [ModelUtils class](http://pastebin.com/UnPWccP5)
- [UploadUtils class](http://pastebin.com/saTCmdD7)
- [ProductsTable class](http://pastebin.com/80tQaKDC)
- [MediasTable class](http://pastebin.com/XpRVnPDF)
- [ProductFeaturesTable class](http://pastebin.com/ks4xTTq4)

Comment: The short answer is that everything after `if($productSaved) {` should be in the afterSave method of the products table class http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave

Comment: @AD7six I put all methods involved in together in ProductsTable file, but when I run this error was launched: http://pastebin.com/5Dxr83H9 (pasted it on pastebin), as ProductsTable got (temporary) http://pastebin.com/yJ0XqDjC

Comment: @AD7six other reasonable solution would be to use RequestAction within the Product Controller?

Comment: ReqeustAction is not a good solution

Comment: @AD7six I try a new approach

Comment: I started writing an answer but it's hard to review when the details you are perhaps focussing on are not that important - the code architecture is wrong. The code should at least look [more like this](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/741ac5ff73a4c9a457a8) - attempting to use the request object in a table class (previous comment) indicates needing to think/understand a little more what you're doing - a table should _never_ need to reference a request object. I don't understand your new approach - it looks the same as the old approach. You may find discussing your code on irc more productive.